# Does a VPN utilizing PPTP and MS-CHAPv2 without encryption pose a risk to security?

Tags: windows, vpn, windows-8

I see there is no encryption for ms chap v2 (providers settings.)

[image: Windows 7 Network Adapters Dialog]

[image: PPTP Security Dialog where encryption is forced off]

[image: nForce adapter dialog]
[image: nForce adapter protocol listing dialog]

Furthermore, what can I do if the provider refuses to cooperate and improve security?

Can a vulnerability in this setup be exploited by people on the same LAN, or between my port and the provider's equipment?

Answer (score 1):

It is a security risk, as *Point-to-Point Tunneling Protocol* (PPTP) is obsolete with many well known security issues.

Thorough explanations from Bruce Schneier's research:

- [Cryptanalysis of Microsoft’s Point-to-Point
  Tunneling Protocol (PPTP)](http://www.schneier.com/paper-pptp.pdf)
- [Cryptanalysis of Microsoft’s PPTP
  Authentication Extensions (MS-CHAPv2)](http://www.schneier.com/paper-pptpv2.pdf)

Easier to digest:

- Olivia Scott: [The PPTP VPN protocol: Is it safe?](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/the-pptp-vpn-protocol-is-it-safe/#gref)
- David Wibergh: [PPTP has become obsolete](https://www.ovpn.com/en/blog/pptp-has-become-obsolete/)
- [Microsoft says don't use PPTP and MS-CHAP](http://www.h-online.com/security/news/item/Microsoft-says-don-t-use-PPTP-and-MS-CHAP-1672257.html)